# Renaming banch of folders using Python and Pandas and data from an excel file

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am in need of renaming more than 1200 folders, from a very brief name to a more appropriate one.
Luckily there is an excel file that I can use, first column containing the current name and the second column discribing what it actually is and a good candidate as a new name.
A small sample of the file is like this:

| name_folder | name_game |
| --- | --- |
| 10THFRAM | 10th Frame |
| 1943 | 1943 the batthe of Midway |
| 20000L | 20000 Leagues |

and so on...

So my first option was to use Python and Pandas (used again some times before for same purposes) and I came to the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import shutil
workdir = r'D:\Python\Jupyter Notebooks\work\final_name\games'
targetdir = r'D:\Python\Jupyter Notebooks\work\final_name\fin'
data = pd.read_excel('hdd_games.xlsx')
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['name_folder', 'name_game'])
for folder in os.listdir(workdir):
    current_folder = os.path.join(workdir, folder)
    temp1 = df[df['name_folder'].str.match(folder)]
    temp2 = temp1[['name_game']]
    newname = temp2['name_game'].iloc[0]
    newtarget = os.path.join(targetdir, newname)
    shutil.copytree(current_folder, newtarget, dirs_exist_ok=True)
```

This code has worked for me in the past. It worked again but there is a problem: folders containing much same characters at the beggining they are all copied to a new one with foldername taken from the last match. Example:

| name_folder | name_game |
| --- | --- |
| XENON2A | Xenon 2 25MB |
| XENON2 | Xenon 2 Regular |
| XENON | Xenon |

Content of all three folders is copied in the same one named Xenon 2 25MB...

So it seems that something is going wrong with the match. Somehow I should be able to get exact match of string in first column. All three items in first column should be copied in their own folder and names according to the same column.
The same code worked for me in the past but there were not folders with identical initial names, so no issues happened.

Can you please help how I should edit code to achive what I need? Or maybe suggest another more appropriate way to have the same result?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what do you want

Comment: A solution or correction to code so each folder is copied to a unique one...